# ruby on rails should i query to db from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am just getting started with Ruby on Rails and i am not sure how i should do the queries to database in order to get data, add data or edit data...

Is it better to find for example a user from the controller or its better to add the queries into the model?

currently, my user homepage controller looks like this with some simple functionality

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  #get current_user variable
  helper_method :current_user

  def index
    if user_signed_in?
        @user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
    else
        render_404
    end
  end
end
```

it simply checks if the user is logged in and finds the user...

Should i move the db calls to a model for best practice or using the above method is also fine?

Comment: I believe this kind of call is fine. The problem is with calls like `User.where("id = ? and active = ? and wealth = ?", current_user.id, true, :rich)`. In this kind of approach it is better to create a scope in the model and call it from the controller like `User.find_active_and_rich`, something like that.

Comment: This pattern makes no sense to me. According to your code, `current_user` is already the object you're fetching. Also if you use `find_by_id!` Rails will handle the RoutingError this method will raise by rendering a 404 itself.

Comment: @injekt yeah this line should be deleted... thanks

Comment: @fxuser if that's the case, you want a `before_filter` to check if the `current_user` is signed in, and if not, redirect them (whether that be a 404 or otherwise)

Comment: @injekt `render_404 if !user_signed_in?` seems to work...

Comment: @fxuser sure, but you still hit the action. `before_filter :render_404, :unless => :user_signed_in?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did it is fine in my opinion. The controller's job is to set the data for the view and part of setting the data is fetching it from the DB.

For more complex DB query you could use [scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scope) which are located in the model. This way the controller does not hold too much logic of DB queries on the model.

Answer (score 2):

You usually want to use a repository pattern which rails gives us by default with active record. I'd say that's perfectly fine. If you had more complex business logic or were pulling from multiple tables, then I'd probably move it into it's own class.